# Ubuntu +Xming on Windows WSL: Can open GUI from ssh + command, but not during SSH session

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

### Quick solution to the question

- On the host machine, do not put any `DISPLAY=` statement there. If exist, the
  remote host will try to render GUI on its own display port;
- On the client machine, do specify `export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0` in the
  `~/.bashrc`. This `DISPLAY` variable  shall match with the `Xming` that runs
  on the client machine.

Then, simply connect to the host using the `-X` flag and enjoy free access to all GUI programs on the remote machine!

---

What went wrong in the lengthy description below:

- As clarified in one of the comments, one should not set the `DISPLAY` variable on the remote host. It is overkill as it confuses how GUIs should have been rendered.

  - Removing the line setting the `DISPLAY` variable on the host solved my problem.

---

I have set a Linux Mint machine to pick up X11Forwarding by specifying the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, yet, I have trouble accessing the server using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS hosted as WSL on Windows 10.

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost no
AllowAgentForwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
AddressFamily inet
```

Yet, after having logged into the Linux Mint machine using `ssh -Y address_of_remote_server`, I cannot launch any programs that has GUI. The following error messages come from trying to launch `gvim` during the SSH session:

[image]

However, I can launch `gvim` by combining the commands, as: `ssh -Y address_of_remote_server gvim`. No error was prompted. **Please advise which setting needs to be tweaked to help me open GUI programs *during* SSH sessions.**

---

More details:

- On the local machine, I use a Ubuntu distro installed as WSL on Windows 10.

  - For X-server, I have tried both Xming and X410. Both can host (local) GUI-programs through display port: `127.0.0.1:0.0` (thus goes the setting on the remote machine as well.)
- On the remote Linux Mint machine, I have set `export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0` as well; the `ssh + command (gvim)` did not work without the `127.0.0.1` part.

---

### Updates, with `-X` flag

I should have opted to show the demo using `-X` flag. In my case, hooking up SSH connections using `-X` and `-Y` are identical. They both have set the `$DISPLAY` variable:
[image]

Similarly, combining the connection statement with the `gvim` command gets me a lively Gvim window. And, I get the following error with connecting first, and then issuing `gvim` command:
[image]

---

### Updates with the client setting

On the client machine, in `~/.ssh/config`, I have set up:

```
host 10.0.0.168
    ForwardX11 yes
    Port 22990 #This is a fake port.
    User llinfeng
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/MyRSA_Key
```

Still, I cannot launch any GUI programs after getting into the SSH session. Again, launching combined commands does yield a fully functional GUI (`ssh -X 10.0.0.168 gvim` will create a GVIM window.)

Comment: I think you need an -X in your ssh command... look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely .... the -X part should set the proper `export display` variable

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force a client to enable `X11Forwarding` by putting an entry in any `sshd_config` file, but instead need to enable `ForwardX11` on the client machine, and for `ssh` **not** `sshd`.  `X11Forwarding` needs to be enabled on the server, but that doesn't mean it's enforced.

You can do this by editing your `~/.ssh/config` for the user, and adding a Host entry for your remote server:

```
Host theserver
Hostname 192.168.1.1
User username
ForwardX11 yes
PubKeyAuthentication yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/some_key
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Now you can run `$ ssh theserver` and `ForwardX11` will be active.  When you use `-X/-Y` flag, you're activating `ForwardX11` on the client, the same as by setting up a configuration.  Either way, you will need to enable `ForwardX11` on the client, and it is **not** recommended to do this system-wide for all hosts, but instead selectively for each host.

Don't mess with `DISPLAY` and allow your client and the system to set everything up.  You were probably trying to fix stuff and added that, but remove it and try simply using `-X`/`-Y` flag, or configuring for X11 Forwarding for the specific host, or with a flag at runtime.

You can read more about the security implications of X11 Forwarding [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/security-concerns-with-x11-forwarding) and elsewhere.

Comment: On the client side, I have set `X11Forwarding` as well. Also, `ssh -X 10.0.0.168 gvim` should get me the GUI interface. It is during normal SSH sessions that I cannot launch any GUI program.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is as simple as connection with -X flag:

```
ssh -X me@myserver
```

This should set proper display variables for you. You can see what the value is like this:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

When I ssh into my host, I get this value for DISPLAY:

```
localhost:10.0
```

You may have more in your server's config file than you need. All I have in mine is the following:

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Try trimming your ssh config file down to these simple values.

Also, the -p 22 is unnecessary as port 22 is the default for ssh.

There is more info here: [Stack Exchange: Forward X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely)

Finally, much can be learned from the manpages:

```
man ssh
```

Comment: I have updated the original question with demos with `-X` flag. I don't see a problem disclosing my local IP. Please advise if I shall also mask my the local IP of the `Z` machine.

Comment: when I ssh to my server with the -X flag, then do `echo $DISPLAY` I get this "localhost:10.0" what happens if you set `export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0`