# Cannot connect to X display using an ssh tunnel in WSL bash

Tags: networking, bash, ssh, xorg, tunnel

I have VcXsrv installed on windows and I run

```
ssh -NfXY -t -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -L 2121:PCNAME:21 -L 2020:PCNAME:20 -L 2222:PCNAME:22 USERNAME@SERVER
```

to tunnel through the university server to my workstation.

I can run `xeyes` in WSL bash locally and it works
`xeyes` fails with `Error: Can't open display: 0.0` 
It also hangs forever if I set DISPLAY to `localhost:0.0`

e.g.

```
[local WSL]> echo $DISPLAY
:0
[local WSL]> xeyes
"runs" 
[local WSL]> ssh -NfXY -t -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -L 2121:PCNAME:21 -L 2020:PCNAME:20 -L 2222:PCNAME:22 USERNAME@SERVER
[workstation]> export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
Error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0
[workstation]> export DISPLAY=:0.0    
[workstation]> xeyes
"hangs with no output"
```

Can anyone help?

EDIT:
I can run this fine from another PC using `localhost:11.0` on the workstation. If I run `xeyes` from the original PC with `localhost:11.0` it uses the other computer!!!

Comment: By default it is localhost:10.0, if I unset that it fails `Error: Can't open display:`

Comment: Unset? Not saying to unset anything.  Saying to not set.  Saying don't mess with it at all.  First step is enabling X11 forwarding.  You're trying to fix issues you don't have by setting that variable because you didn't turn X11 forwarding on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [you need to enable `ForwardX11` on the client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157029/can-open-gui-from-ssh-command-but-not-during-ssh-session/1157129#1157129) and `X11Forwarding` on the remote host in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Then, try **without** adjusting `DISPLAY` on your workstation/remote machine first.  Only set the `DISPLAY` variable after you've ensured everything else is set up to work correctly.  You shouldn't have to set this but it is possible.

I believe that the command 'hangs forever' because it is being displayed on the remote machine (which you likely cannot see).

Sometimes it's good to simplify things and try to solve one problem at a time.  Have you tried dropping the port forwarding and everything else and focused on getting X11 Forwarding working in a simple setup?

---

**Summary**: Asker enabled `ForwardX11` on the client and set `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` only after initial attempt resulted in

```
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: Connection refused Error: Can't open display: localhost:13.0
```

Comment: I've made an edit: Another PC can run it fine without any adjustments (see above).

Comment: `X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10` on client

Comment: @Lucidnonsense `X11Forwarding` is a server configuration, while `ForwardX11` is a client configuration.  Please slow down and read the information being provided carefully.

Comment: OK, having implemented the above, and trying it on a non-tunnelled  connection it now says `connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: Connection refused
Error: Can't open display: localhost:13.0`

Comment: I had to make that directory

Comment: Okay, *now* give `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` a shot, but now you have a more accurate error to work with.  Please update your question with all of these details if it doesn't work so we can figure it out.

Comment: OK got it. Solved. They needed to be different...